# Optimizing OpenGL: VAOs vs Shader Organization

Tags: opengl, optimization, 3d, glsl, shader

I'm writing some code that will be drawing a number of 3D models to the screen, ultimately for a sort of 3D world. Each model could have meshes within it that use different shaders for rendering. In terms of making things run efficiently, I know that you should try to minimize OpenGL calls, namely those switching VAO and those switching shaders as they're supposed to have a lot of overhead.

In my implementation, each model has its geometry organized into a VAO. VAOs can have meshes that will differ in material settings but not necessarily shaders.

**My question**: Is it better to bind a VAO and render it entirely in one go, switching shaders if needed along the way, or to bind one shader and run through all of the (subsets of the ) VAOs that use that question.  The first would be redundantly binding shaders, the second would be redundantly binding VAOs, so **is it better to minimize shader binding calls or VAO binding calls?**

I realize this is rather open ended and seems like it could depend on the application, however I would also be interested to know how I could find out how much gl operations cost (overhead? dependencies?), or how I could figure them out, as that would provide the information necessary to construct a proper response for whatever the scenario is. Also, if there's a better way to organize my project to begin with, that insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way to find out is to profile it.

Comment: I'd too be interested in finding out the impact to FPS. You can probably tweak your code to either bind each triangle separately or to toggle the shader between each triangle.